# Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

im trying to use group by and sum in Laravel but this error code appear im new in Laravel and 
and this is my code

```
 $pemilik=DB::table("tb_simpanan")
                                     ->selectRaw('anggota_id,SUM(nominal_transaksi) as count')
                                     ->groupBy('anggota_id')
                                     ->get();  
                          $id1=1;
                          $data=DB::table('tb_master_bunga_simpanan')->where('id',$id1)->first();
                          $bunga=$data->persentase;
                          foreach($pemilik as $pem) {
                              $pem2[]=$pem->anggota_id;
                              $pem1[]=$bunga*$pem->count;     
                          }
                          $jumlah=sizeof($pem1);
                          $tanggal=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                          $test=3;
                        $idUser=Session::get('id');
                          $idUser1=DB::table('tb_anggota')->where('id',$idUser)->first();
                          for($i=1;$i<=$jumlah;$i++){
                              $data=[
                                    'anggota_id'=>$pem2[$i-1],
                                    'tanggal'=>$tanggal,
                                    'jenis_transaksi'=>$test,
                                    'nominal_transaksi'=>$pem1[$i-1],
                                    'id_user'=>$idUser1,
                               ];

                                DB::table('tb_simpanan')->insert($data);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iUn0u.png)

Comment: Please upload the screenshot of error page. That can help you to debug from those codes.

Comment: I don't get it can u tell which part of my code should is wrong? and can u tell me what code should I change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace:

```
'id_user'=>$idUser1,
```

With

```
'id_user'=>$idUser1->id,
```

Or other attribute you may think suits better.

Comment: No problem @bramastavikana .. if it works for you, please mark the answer as accepted to help others with the same issue.